# RoR: How to add make link_to point to current URL and add a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby On Rails 3.x

Multiple views of a controller call one and the same partial, as 90% of the partial is the same for all the views, the other 10% are handled via IF/ENDIF in the partial.

Now I need a link to the current URL and pass it a parameter, e.g. if the current URL is`http://myapp.com/welcome/index_1` then I need a link to `http://myapp/welcome/index_1?par=abcd`
With

```
<%=link_to "Info",url_for(:only_path=>true)%>
```

I get the link to the current URL, but how to add the additional parameter.

```
<%=link_to "Info",url_for(:only_path=>true,:par=>"abcd")%>
```

isn't working, neither is:

```
<%=link_to "Info",url_for(:only_path=>true), :par=>"abcd"%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "info", url_for(par: "abcd") %>
```

Comment: strange scenario: if this is used within a partial, the url_for points to the partial (i.e. /users/my_partial?param_here=true). Any advice on getting past that?